# MYSQL statement: lookup how many records exist how many times in other table

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 database tables:

Table 1:

```
+---------+-------+-------------+
| Page    | Title | Description |
+---------+-------+-------------+
| Apple   | ..... | ........... |
| Orange  | ..... | ........... |
| Pear    | ..... | ........... |
| Grapes  | ..... | ........... |
+---------+-------+-------------+
```

Table 2:

```
+----------+-------------+
|   Link   |    Page     |
+----------+-------------+
| Website1 |    Apple    |
| Website2 |    Orange   |
| Website3 |    Apple    |
| Website4 |    Orange   |
| Website5 |    Apple    |
| Website6 |    Pear     |
| Website7 |    Apple    |
| Website8 |    Grapes   |
| Website9 |    Grapes   |
+----------+-------------+
```

I want to know/return how many pages from Table 1 are referenced in Table 2 and how many times they are referenced. (I DON'T want to know how many times EACH page in Table 1 is referenced in Table 2).

So in this example:
1 page is referenced 1 time (Pear),
2 pages are referenced 2 times (Grapes and Orange) &
1 page is referenced 4 times.

What kind of SQL statement would I use to get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following query should do..

```
SELECT COUNT(1) NoOfPages,CNT ReferencedTimes
FROM
(
    SELECT T2.PAGE,COUNT(1) CNT
    FROM TABLE1 T1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.PAGE = T2.PAGE
    GROUP BY T2.PAGE
)T
GROUP BY CNT
```

Comment: This worked perfectly after 1 slight change:
I changed "SELECT T2.PAGE,COUNT(1) CNT" to:
SELECT T1.PAGE,COUNT(1) CNT".

Answer (score 0):

I think the following statement will fit:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM Table2 WHERE (Table2.Page IN (SELECT Page FROM Table1));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT page)) AS Page,page_count 
      FROM
          (SELECT table1.Page as page,COUNT(*) as page_count
           FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.Page=table2.Page
          GROUP BY table1.Page)
       as T GROUP BY page_count
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It seems that you missed one detail "(I DON'T want to know how many times EACH page in Table 1 is referenced in Table 2)."

Comment: Possibly. But I'm too lazy to analyze it in details =) As for me, your query is too heavy and complicated for such an easy task. Please, consider my option in answer below, I think it will fit and it's much more easier to understand. http://stackoverflow.com/a/33412431/1946038

Answer (score 0):

> Use This query

```
Select table2.page,cnt(table2.page) 
                          from table1 inner join table2 
                        On table1.Page=table2.Page group by table2.page
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you are seeking is X page was referenced N times, the below query will achieve that:

```
SELECT COUNT(t1.page), t2.count
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT page,COUNT(*) AS count FROM table2 GROUP BY page) t2 ON t1.page=t2.page
GROUP BY t2.count
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query, it will make a left join and tell you how many times item is referenced in table2, if count is zero than no reference in the other table

```
SELECT table1.Page, count(table2.Page) as count
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.Page = table1.Page
GROUP BY table1.Page
```